# Get mouse position in child QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, qt5

In Qt5, I have a main window with a scene:

```
MyWindow::MyWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    view = new QGraphicsView();
    scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    scene->installEventFilter(this);
    view->setScene(scene);
    ...
    setCentralWidget(view);
}
```

`view` and `scene` are both private members of `MyWindow`. **I want to know, in the `MyWindow` class,  the mouse position when I click on the scene.** That's why I use `installEventFilter` above. And I have tried to catch the event with this:

```
bool MyWindow::eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event)
{
    if (target == scene)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneMousePress)
        {
            const QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* const me = static_cast<const QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*>(event);
            const QPointF position = me->pos();
            cout << position.x() << "," << position.y() << endl;
        }
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(target, event);
}
```

This code does not work as expected: The position it prints when I click on the scene is always 0,0. Any clue about what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent.pos()` returns position in coordinates of item on which you clicked. Your scene has no items so it returns (0,0). If you want to get position in scene coordinates use scenePos().

```
const QPointF position = me->scenePos();
```